# How do I programmatically get the version of a DLL or EXE file?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, version, exe

I need to get the product version and file version for a DLL or EXE file using Win32 native APIs in C or C++. I'm *not* looking for the Windows version, but the version numbers that you see by right-clicking on a DLL file, selecting "Properties", then looking at the "Details" tab. This is usually a four-part dotted version number x.x.x.x.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: [GetFileVersionInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647003(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Doesn't matter if he just wants Win32 API calls. Any language that supports calling system DLLs should be fine.

Comment: Edited to clarify that this is about C/C++.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You would use the [GetFileVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647003.aspx) API.

See [Using Version Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646985(VS.85).aspx) on the MSDN site.

Sample:

```
DWORD  verHandle = 0;
UINT   size      = 0;
LPBYTE lpBuffer  = NULL;
DWORD  verSize   = GetFileVersionInfoSize( szVersionFile, &verHandle);

if (verSize != NULL)
{
    LPSTR verData = new char[verSize];

    if (GetFileVersionInfo( szVersionFile, verHandle, verSize, verData))
    {
        if (VerQueryValue(verData,"\\",(VOID FAR* FAR*)&lpBuffer,&size))
        {
            if (size)
            {
                VS_FIXEDFILEINFO *verInfo = (VS_FIXEDFILEINFO *)lpBuffer;
                if (verInfo->dwSignature == 0xfeef04bd)
                {

                    // Doesn't matter if you are on 32 bit or 64 bit,
                    // DWORD is always 32 bits, so first two revision numbers
                    // come from dwFileVersionMS, last two come from dwFileVersionLS
                    TRACE( "File Version: %d.%d.%d.%d\n",
                    ( verInfo->dwFileVersionMS >> 16 ) & 0xffff,
                    ( verInfo->dwFileVersionMS >>  0 ) & 0xffff,
                    ( verInfo->dwFileVersionLS >> 16 ) & 0xffff,
                    ( verInfo->dwFileVersionLS >>  0 ) & 0xffff
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    delete[] verData;
}
```

Comment: `int revision = HIWORD(verInfo->dwProductVersionLS); 
 int build = LOWORD(verInfo->dwProductVersionLS);`

Comment: I know it has been a while, but for newbies like me this is how you get the .exe filename: `TCHAR szVersionFile[MAX_PATH];
 GetModuleFileName(NULL, szVersionFile, MAX_PATH );`

Comment: @BurninatorDor Don't call yourself a newbie.  I've been programming in MFC for 6 years thus far, and this helped me.

Comment: edited this answer because it was calculating the version numbers wrong. From the MSDN docs for dwProductVersionMS: "The most significant 32 bits of the file's binary version number. This member is used with dwFileVersionLS to form a 64-bit value used for numeric comparisons."  , so you use both of them to calculate the version number. First two (major / minor) are in versionMS and last two (revision / build) are in versionLS. It doesn't matter if you are in 32/64 bit, DWORD is always 32 bits.

Comment: Make sure to link to libversion.a for MingW. See here for copy-pastable example: http://pastebin.com/sYZCVpfw

Comment: `NULL` should not be used with `DWORD`s (`0` would be correct instead)

Comment: Have to add version.lib to additional linker dependences. Referencing Mincore.lib as official docs suggest didn't work for me.

Comment: How to get file version for MSI files, GetFileVersionInfoSize giving error 1812

Comment: @user3664223 It is possible that a MSI file may not have that information block.

Answer (score 23):

All these solutions did not work properly (with my system). I found out that each of the four parts of the version number are saved as a 16-bit value.

The first two numbers are saved in the 32-bit DWORD dwFileVersionMS, and the second two in dwFileVersionLS. So I edited your code at the output section like this:

```
    TRACE( "File Version: %d.%d.%d.%d\n",
        ( pFileInfo->dwFileVersionMS >> 16 ) & 0xffff,
        ( pFileInfo->dwFileVersionMS >>  0 ) & 0xffff,
        ( pFileInfo->dwFileVersionLS >> 16 ) & 0xffff,
        ( pFileInfo->dwFileVersionLS >>  0 ) & 0xffff
        );
```

And it works perfectly. The output is formatted like on my system:

### major.minor.build.revision

Comment: How to get file version for MSI files, GetFileVersionInfoSize giving error 1812?

Answer (score 20):

You get this information using [the version information APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646981.aspx). Here is a sample:

```
void PrintFileVersion( TCHAR *pszFilePath )
{
    DWORD               dwSize              = 0;
    BYTE                *pbVersionInfo      = NULL;
    VS_FIXEDFILEINFO    *pFileInfo          = NULL;
    UINT                puLenFileInfo       = 0;

    // Get the version information for the file requested
    dwSize = GetFileVersionInfoSize( pszFilePath, NULL );
    if ( dwSize == 0 )
    {
        printf( "Error in GetFileVersionInfoSize: %d\n", GetLastError() );
        return;
    }

    pbVersionInfo = new BYTE[ dwSize ];

    if ( !GetFileVersionInfo( pszFilePath, 0, dwSize, pbVersionInfo ) )
    {
        printf( "Error in GetFileVersionInfo: %d\n", GetLastError() );
        delete[] pbVersionInfo;
        return;
    }

    if ( !VerQueryValue( pbVersionInfo, TEXT("\\"), (LPVOID*) &pFileInfo, &puLenFileInfo ) )
    {
        printf( "Error in VerQueryValue: %d\n", GetLastError() );
        delete[] pbVersionInfo;
        return;
    }

    // pFileInfo->dwFileVersionMS is usually zero. However, you should check
    // this if your version numbers seem to be wrong

    printf( "File Version: %d.%d.%d.%d\n",
        ( pFileInfo->dwFileVersionLS >> 24 ) & 0xff,
        ( pFileInfo->dwFileVersionLS >> 16 ) & 0xff,
        ( pFileInfo->dwFileVersionLS >>  8 ) & 0xff,
        ( pFileInfo->dwFileVersionLS >>  0 ) & 0xff
        );

    // pFileInfo->dwProductVersionMS is usually zero. However, you should check
    // this if your version numbers seem to be wrong.

    printf( "Product Version: %d.%d.%d.%d\n",
        ( pFileInfo->dwProductVersionLS >> 24 ) & 0xff,
        ( pFileInfo->dwProductVersionLS >> 16 ) & 0xff,
        ( pFileInfo->dwProductVersionLS >>  8 ) & 0xff,
        ( pFileInfo->dwProductVersionLS >>  0 ) & 0xff
        );

    delete[] pbVersionInfo;
}
```

Comment: I think this is wrong. for file version 1.0.0.1 this function gives me "0.0.0.1".

I ended up @Vasya 's answer

Comment: There is a memory leak. `pbVersionInfo` is not released at the end of the function.

Answer (score 5):

This code shows the file version numbers correctly.

```
( pFileInfo->dwFileVersionMS >> 16 ) & 0xff,
( pFileInfo->dwFileVersionMS >> 0 ) & 0xff,
( pFileInfo->dwFileVersionLS >>  16 ) & 0xff,
( pFileInfo->dwFileVersionLS >>  0 ) & 0xff);
```

Comment: Can you provide some context to this answer? It seems to be incomplete. If it was a correction to another answer, please leave a comment on it, or edit that answer and it will be approved by a more experianced user.

Comment: this will definitely _not_ work correctly, if the version includes any component greater than 255, e.g. 6.1.3709.2
The four components are 16-bit numbers, not 8-bit.

Comment: This is not correct. The individual parts of the versions are 16-bit values. The code should be

( pFileInfo->dwFileVersionMS >> 16 ) & 0xffff,
( pFileInfo->dwFileVersionMS >> 0 ) & 0xffff,
( pFileInfo->dwFileVersionLS >>  16 ) & 0xffff,
( pFileInfo->dwFileVersionLS >>  0 ) & 0xffff);

Comment: As it was a long time ago !!! But I can share the solution. I then refused to receive information about executable files from the kernel driver. I then transferred this function to the service. The driver transmitted information about the start of the process and expected a resolution from the service

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use the [GetFileVersionInfoEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969434(VS.85).aspx) or [GetFileVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647003(VS.85).aspx) API functions.

You can also do it from within your application resources as explained [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/GetLocalVersionInfos.aspx).