# Unable to set the Version Information for Self Extractor in IExpress

Tags: self-extracting, iexpress

Actually, trying to set a Version Info, for self extractor created through IExpress. After searching I got the following [LINK](http://www.mdgx.com/INF_web/custver.htm), whereas, it does not recognize the values from Version Section, default values from Wextract.exe are being published every time. Seems to be IExpress ignoring the [VersionSection]. I tried the following in the SED File.

```
[Options]
VersionInfo=VersionSection;
[VersionSection]
FromFile=MYApp.MSI;
```

Please help me to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to remove those semicolons.

Second, the `FromFile` needs to have the right type of version information. MSI files don't seem to have this information. When you view a file's properties there should be a *Version* tab if the file has version information. (You can see easily enough that MSI files lack this tab, and thus that version information.)

A working example:

```
[Options]
VersionInfo=VersionSection
[VersionSection]
FromFile=notepad.exe
```

For those curious, `iexpress.exe` reads the version information from the `FromFile` using the [`GetFileVersionInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647003.aspx) API. There's a great [worked example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940707/how-do-i-programatically-get-the-version-of-a-dll-or-exe-file) here on Stack Overflow.