# How to get the firefox and it's variants version in C++ on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, firefox, browser

Firefox has a lot of variants, like Waterfox, Palemoon, etc.

How can I get the version number of all Firefox and it's variant browsers present on a system?

Using C++ and Win32 SDK.

Another related question, how do I know if a browser is derived off Firefox or Chrome (like Comodo)?

Comment: How do you even locate all the browsers on a system?

Comment: To begin with, I'll probably know which all browsers to look for.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Clients\StartMenuInternet   // <-- x64 only
```

where all the browsers (even portable ones) should registers themselves ([source](http://www.rhizohm.net/irhetoric/post/2009/04/03/0a-Finding-All-Installed-Browsers-in-Windows-XP-and-Vista-ndash3b-beware-64bit!0a-.aspx)).
Then you lookup `command` subkey for the browser's main executable path. For example, my portable Chromium is found here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Chromium.Y75GGO62VNIN4R2QLYJDH66X4I\shell\open\command
```

After that you can pull browser version from .exe directly - [How do I programatically get the version of a DLL or EXE file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940707/how-do-i-programatically-get-the-version-of-a-dll-or-exe-file). You can check this version information in GUI as well - go to file Properties (via right-click Context Menu), then Details tab.

It worked for me for portable Chromium, but didn't try it on other non-standard browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox\CurrentVersion