# Getting Access Violation Error using GetFileVersionInfo

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
    DWORD dwHandle;

    DWORD dwSize = GetFileVersionInfoSizeEx( FILE_VER_GET_NEUTRAL , strFilePath.c_str() , &dwHandle );
    if( dwSize == 0 )
        break;
    pVersionInfo = new BYTE[ dwSize ];
    bRetVal = GetFileVersionInfoEx( FILE_VER_GET_NEUTRAL , strFilePath.c_str() ,dwHandle , dwSize , &pVersionInfo );
    if( bRetVal == false )
        break;
    UINT uLen;
    VS_FIXEDFILEINFO *pFileInfo;

    bRetVal = VerQueryValue( &pVersionInfo , L"\\" , (LPVOID *)&pFileInfo , &uLen );

    if( bRetVal == false )
        break;
    DWORD dwFileVersionMS = pFileInfo->dwFileVersionMS;
    DWORD dwFileVersionLS = pFileInfo->dwFileVersionLS;

    DWORD dwLeftMost     = HIWORD(dwFileVersionMS);
    DWORD dwSecondLeft   = LOWORD(dwFileVersionMS);
    DWORD dwSecondRight  = HIWORD(dwFileVersionLS);
    DWORD dwRightMost    = LOWORD(dwFileVersionLS);

    strVersion.sprintf( L"%u.%u.%u.%u", dwLeftMost , dwSecondLeft , dwSecondRight , dwRightMost );
}while(0);
if( pVersionInfo )
    delete []pVersionInfo;
return bRetVal;
```

While debugging this code i am getting access violation error at delete statement . . can anyone tell what i am doing wrong.

Comment: I feel bad correcting the title, "access violent" is way more badass than "access violation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the line

```
bRetVal = GetFileVersionInfoEx( FILE_VER_GET_NEUTRAL , strFilePath.c_str() ,dwHandle , dwSize , &pVersionInfo );
```

The correct call should be

```
bRetVal = GetFileVersionInfoEx( FILE_VER_GET_NEUTRAL , strFilePath.c_str() ,dwHandle , dwSize , pVersionInfo );
```

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
BOOL WINAPI GetFileVersionInfoEx(
  _In_        DWORD dwFlags,
  _In_        LPCTSTR lptstrFilename,
  _Reserved_  DWORD dwHandle,
  _In_        DWORD dwLen,
  _Out_       LPVOID lpData
);
```

The function `GetFileVersionInfoEx()` will fill the buffer pointed to by lpData (or, in the corrected above example, pVersionInfo) with the version info.  In your code, it would be changing the value of the pointer, making it point to somewhere else in memory.

When you call `delete[]`, it is giving you the exception because the value of your pointer has changed and it is no longer the value set by the `new []` operator.  In other words you are trying to free memory that was not dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 2):

The error is that you pass a pointer to the pointer to the allocated data block as the first argument to `VerQueryValue`, which leads to you passing the wrong address to the function. This leads to *undefined behavior* as `VerQueryValue` reads data from, and writes data to, somewhere in memory where it should not be read from/written to.

The solution is to not use the address-of operator here.

---

**Update:** you do the same thing with the `GetFileVersionInfoEx` function call. Don't use the address-of operator for `pVersionInfo`.

Comment: Need to specify which 'address-of' operator for this answer to be helpful... I *think* you mean `pVersionInfo` instead of `&pVersionInfo`.

Comment: Looks like call to `GetFileVersionInfoEx` is similarly wrong!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940707/how-do-i-programatically-get-the-version-of-a-dll-or-exe-file) is the solution yo your issue in another thread with a full code example, but as pointed out the issue is that you are passing the pointer to the buffer for the information the wrong way, no need for the `address of` opearator.

Here is a snipplet with your code fixed to be working:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>

#pragma comment(lib, "version.lib")

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const wchar_t* strFilePath = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\kernel32.dll";
    DWORD dwHandle;
    BOOL bRetVal;
    DWORD dwSize = GetFileVersionInfoSizeEx( FILE_VER_GET_NEUTRAL , strFilePath , &dwHandle );
    if( dwSize == 0 )
        return;
    BYTE* pVersionInfo = new BYTE[dwSize];
    bRetVal = GetFileVersionInfoEx( FILE_VER_GET_NEUTRAL , strFilePath , dwHandle , dwSize , pVersionInfo );
    if( bRetVal == false )
        return;
    UINT uLen;
    VS_FIXEDFILEINFO *pFileInfo = NULL;

    bRetVal = VerQueryValue( pVersionInfo , L"\\" , (LPVOID *)&pFileInfo , &uLen );

    if( bRetVal == false )
        return;
    DWORD dwFileVersionMS = pFileInfo->dwFileVersionMS;
    DWORD dwFileVersionLS = pFileInfo->dwFileVersionLS;

    DWORD dwLeftMost     = HIWORD(dwFileVersionMS);
    DWORD dwSecondLeft   = LOWORD(dwFileVersionMS);
    DWORD dwSecondRight  = HIWORD(dwFileVersionLS);
    DWORD dwRightMost    = LOWORD(dwFileVersionLS);

    char pVersion[1024];
    sprintf(pVersion, "%u.%u.%u.%u", dwLeftMost , dwSecondLeft , dwSecondRight , dwRightMost );
    if( pVersionInfo )
        delete []pVersionInfo;
}
```