# How to get the file version in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qfileinfo

How to get the file version from `File properties\Details\File version` in Qt?

I didn't find it in `QFileInfo`.

Comment: Which kind of files are you referring to?

Comment: There is not general property for files called 'file version'. It has to do with specific type which has that property.

Comment: I work with *.dll files.

Comment: I seriously doubt there is such functionality in Qt. Here is Win32 API solution: [click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940707/how-do-i-programatically-get-the-version-of-a-dll-or-exe-file). Not all DLLs contain version info.

Comment: @Drop sounds like you've answered the question. Maybe you could type that up?

Comment: @Hurr In the end, how did you do it? Does it work cross-platform, or, at least, does interfere ? (it would be nice to work with QCoreApplication::applicationVersion())

Comment: you can get the current qt version with qVersion() from <QtGlobal>, there also is QLibraryInfo::version(), see doc of QtGlobal and QLibraryInfo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not implemented in Qt. You can find an example of how to do it integrated with Qt [here](http://amin-ahmadi.com/2015/04/03/get-exe-version-using-windows-api-in-qt/).