# Api to get product version for application in the dll?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I am working on a cpp application which generates a dll e.g `base.dll` . I have some applications that use this dll e.g `A.exe`, `B.exe` .

I am trying to get the product version of `A.exe` and `B.exe` in `base.dll`. I am using c++11 and boost.
I am compiling this dll for both Windows and Linux.

Currently I am able to get the process name using boost by doing something like this:

`std::string pname = boost::log::aux::get_process_name();`

I am looking for a similar API to get the product version. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you make a function in your base.dll that just returns a std::string?

Comment: Win32 API: `GetModuleHandle` passing in NULL; then `GetModuleFileName` passing in the module handle; then `GetFileVersionInfo` passing in the file name.  Boost no idea.  Links https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199(v=vs.85).aspx  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647003(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @AnonMail can you elaborate on the implementation of function? I need the product version from the exe. I am setting that version in the application using CMAKE.

Comment: @UmangMukeshMehta when you say you are setting the version, what exactly does that mean?  Having the version as part of the exe name?

Comment: @RichardCritten I did get info on the API by following the S.O http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940707/how-do-i-programatically-get-the-version-of-a-dll-or-exe-file. But I am looking for something that can be cross compiled so that I can use it for Linux too.

Comment: @AnonMail I am using cmake to compile all the dll's and the application. I set the BUILD_NUMBER in cmake which is used for all my projects. So for one of the application in csharp I use the BUILD_NUMBER from CMAKE and set the AssemblyFileVersion and AssemblyVersion when compiling. What I need is during run-time of the application a way for it to convey to the dll the version.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CMAKE and the Asssembly terms you've used.  Sorry.