# Define name of build out of code C++ / VS2019

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2019

I´m searching an option to chnage the name of my build solution file out of the source code.
I use Visual Studio 2019 and work on C++ DLL Projects.
I´d like to add a Version as kind of suffix to the builded dll´s name e.g FancyFunctionDll_V01_00_10.dll
While 01_00_10 is something i can change in my source code because there is already a variable storing the version information.

How can I append this to the builds name ?

I´m just able to append it by hand in the project configuration.

Thanks for any help.

Best regards
Stefan

Comment: Have a look into properties of project: Config/Linker/Output file. You may edit the settings and use the offered macros as well (found in the cheat sheet in edit dialog).

Comment: Thank you for the hint. But unfortunately I don´t know how to deal with those macros.

Comment: You can do without the macros if you like. However, these macros are really helpful. Click into input line. There should appear a button with popup menu at end. Click on Edit in the popup menu. Then, there should appear a small Editor dialog. In this dialog there is a button "Macros>>" where you get the cheat-sheet. (Please, bear with me. My VS is in German. I had to translate everything back to English "freehanded".)

Comment: So, me I´m german as well, so is there something like private message, then we can write in german...

Comment: I suggest you could try to use [GetFileVersionInfoA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/winver/nf-winver-getfileversioninfoa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to get the DLL version programmatically. For more details I suggest you could refer to the link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940707/how-do-i-programmatically-get-the-version-of-a-dll-or-exe-file. And then you could add the version number to property -> Linker -> Output file.